# Create gradle wrapper using newest stable Gradle version

Tags: build, wrapper, gradle

I want to create a wrapper, who finds the newest stable version and to use it.
If it is 1.5 to download it and use it , if it is 1.7, then to download it.
Now using code like this doesn't works.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = "1.+"  
}
```

Can I somehow check which is the newest version and to use it instead the "+" sign, which doesn't work now?

PS: Now for every new version I have to change and my wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you are describing is asked for occasionally, but it isn't currently supported.